# Handwriting notes in a notebook PC?

Tags: windows-7, laptop, handwriting

How can I directly write hand written notes onto my Windows 7 notebook PC?

Most software applications like Paint only allow drawing simple figures like lines. I cant afford a tablet or smartphone or such.

Comment: Use paint's pencil tool? Although hand writing with a mouse is very difficult but I'll assume you can't afford a drawing table either, so you may not have much option.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need an external drawing tables or a really good trackpad, where you can literally draw with your fingers/pen. But I would highly recommend a drawing-tablet. There are cheap ones available which should be good enough for your needs.